# How to map entity with JPA?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I can't get the right mapping for the field tree in this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SushiMapTree")
public class SushiMapTree<K, V> extends Persistable implements Map<K,V> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="SushiMapID")
protected int ID;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="SushiMapTree_SushiTree")
private SushiTree<SushiMapElement<K, V>> tree = new SushiTree<SushiMapElement<K,V>>();
```

This are the other classes and their mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SushiTree")
public class SushiTree<T> extends Persistable implements Collection<T> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="SushiTreeID")
protected int ID;

@Column(name="Test")
private String test = "Test";

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="SushiTree_SushiTreeElements")
private List<SushiTreeElement<T>> treeElements = new ArrayList<SushiTreeElement<T>>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="SushiTree_SushiTreeRootElements")
private List<SushiTreeElement<T>> treeRootElements = new ArrayList<SushiTreeElement<T>>();
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SushiMapElement")
public class SushiMapElement<K, V> extends Persistable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int ID;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private SushiMapElement<K, V> parent;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<SushiMapElement<K, V>> children = new ArrayList<SushiMapElement<K, V>>();

@Column(name = "MapKey")
K key;

@Column(name = "MapValue")
V value;
```

The other classes work well, but I can't get the right mapping. I tried different mappings for some hours with Column, JoinColumn, JoinTable and so on. Eclipse Link does not create the database and says to use a ValueHolderInterface:

```
The attribute [tree] is not declared as type ValueHolderInterface, but its mapping uses indirection.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following annotation:

```
   @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name="TreeID")
```

But I don't know, why it work this way.